# file or directory '<project>/<app>/src/debug/java', not found

Tags: android, gradle, android-library

My project doesn't build. I imported a third party project with library and sample module into Android Studio.

The project is here https://github.com/consp1racy/android-support-preference.git

Both modules have Build Variant set to **debug**. When I build the project it fails on the sample module with error message:

> file or directory 'project/sample/src/debug/java', not found

Setting the build variant of sample module to **release** produces a similar message:

> file or directory 'project/sample/src/release/java', not found

I'm puzzled. I would expect the source path to be src/main/java.

What is going on here?

Comment: I'm guessing the Gradle file specified different code paths? Can you add it please?

Comment: The gradle files do not specify src code paths at all.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this thrid-party project, then?

Comment: Of course: https://github.com/consp1racy/android-support-preference.git

Comment: Can you please add your Gradle file as I first asked?

Comment: You should post your settings.gradle and your structure. It is not clear how you are importing the modules inside your project

Comment: my settings.gradle contains one line: include ':library', ':sample'. Does it help? Which gradle files would you need?

Comment: The original author of the project made an update and now it builds fine with gradle from the command line. In Android Studio it still has issues with resourcePrefix asp_:
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"No resource identifier found for attribute \u0027asp_simpleMenu\u0027 in package \u0027net.xpece.android.support.preference.sample\u0027","sources":[{"file":"/opt/projects/android3rd.workspace/android-support-preference/sample/src/main/res/xml/pref_data_sync.xml","position":{"startLine":4}}],"original":"","tool":"AAPT"}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The original author of the project made an update and now it builds fine with gradle from the command line.

Comment: Absolutely. I love that project.